# ionic2 How to set option value="..." to keep number 0,1,2,3,

Tags: arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to counting the amount that `@NAME` for setting an array for the FACET and showing the `@KEY` per `FACET[]` which seems to be the end goal.

Yes, you totally know what I meant. But I want output is every `@KEY` of that `FACET[]`

**Example :**

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="refine" (ionChange)="optionsFn();">
            <ion-option value="..." *ngFor="let item of date">{{item["@NAME"]}},({{item["@COUNT"]}})</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
<ion-list>          
          <ion-item *ngFor="let item of foundRepos" (click)="itemClicked($event,item)">
            <h3> {{ item[@KEY"] }}</h3>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

.

```
            this.http.get("my_url")
                        .subscribe(data =>{
                                 this.date=data.json().RESULT.FACET; //get @NAME
                        },error=>{
                            err => console.error(err),
                           () => console.log('getRepos completed')
            );
        console.log(this.date);

      }

     optionsFn(): void {

       this.http.get("my_url")
                        .subscribe(data =>{
                                 this.foundRepos=data.json().RESULT.FACET[0,1,2,3.4......].FACET_VALUES; ///get @KEY
                        },error=>{
                            console.log(error);
                        } );

      }
```

from above `ion-select` is show `creator , lang and bnb` ,I want to If When I select `lang` `ion-option value="..."` to keep `number` of `"@NAME"`

- **example** counting amount of @NAME is 3 and
- when I select `creator` is `ion-option value="..."` << is 0
- when I select `lang` is `ion-option value="..."` << is 1
- when I select `bnb` is `ion-option value="..."` << is 2
- and If I get `value` ,I take it to  `goToapply()` for set `FACET[]`

example I select `bnb` I get `value =2` and `console.log (this.refine)` is show `2`
take it(2) to  `let p = this.refine` , so that `p = 2`
take `p` to `this.foundRepos=data.json().RESULT.FACET[p].FACET_VALUES;` for show `@KEY` in `ion-list`

- When I select lang output on `ion-list` is

> tha
>
> eng

But I don't know to set option value="..." to keep number 0,1,2,3 respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood the question
I think you want a counter on your for

```
<ion-option [value]="i" *ngFor="let item of date;let i = index">{{item["@NAME"]}},({{item["@COUNT"]}})</ion-option>
```

The [] makes it runtime calculated and index is a special ranged variable you can use there.

Comment: Sorry my English is not so good. T-T ,and thank you, much appreciated!